# Firebase - no displayName for user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I can add users in Firebase console -> Auth but I can't do anything more than setting an email and password for them.

Could I in some way set for them displayName?

Answer (score 11):

I guess if you just want to update users profile:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    user.updateProfile({
        displayName: "Random Name"
    }).then(function() {
        // Update successful.
    }, function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    });

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Additionally: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Yes, I know what fields authData has but I know also that authData has a field named "displayName" which is null for that type of authentication. For example, when I use Google authentication, then i have in response displayName as my Google name and surname. So my question is, do I can to set such properties for users that I create manually in firebase console. Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to set the display name in the console (good feature request though). Until that exists, calling the API is the way to go.

Comment: I found this page by googling  "firebase console edit user profile" because I, too, wanted to set a user's `displayName` via the console and was surprised to find I couldn't. Definitely a feature that should be added.

Comment: What you could do to make things easy is to ask for the user to enter a display name when signing up and then save their input to the database under for arguments sake a child object called "Users" then whenever you would like to get the user's display name use DatabaseReference variable to get the value of the user's name and display it.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a user you create it only with email and password but you can and the displayName in the promise, then inside the .then() method you call the updateProfile method and you are ready, right down is the code:

```
  onSubmit(formData) {
    if(formData.valid) {
      console.log(formData.value);
      this.af.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        formData.value.email,
        formData.value.password
      ).then(
        (success) => {
         console.log(success); 
        success.updateProfile({
          displayName: "Example User",
          photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
        }).catch(
        (err) => {
        this.error = err;
        });        
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      }).catch(
        (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      })
    }
  }
```

Note that in my example the displayName is set to "Example User", in the real app you just add the parameter as in my case it should be -> displayName:formData.value.name