# Add user displayname

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I add a `DisplayName` in FireStore?  I have read [firebase no displayname for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227139/firebase-no-displayname-for-user) and [firebase user photourl and displayname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334382/firebase-user-photourl-and-displayname) and [this](https://medium.com/@doyinolarewaju/firebase-adding-extra-information-to-user-on-sign-up-and-other-tips-4ebe215866e) but none of them work, since they all refer to Firebase and not Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a cloud function that triggers on account creation as such

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const firebaseUser = event.data;

    return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set({
       name: firebaseUser.displayName || "n/a"
    });
});
```

That will create a document for the user in a collection called users, identified by its UID. Beware that the `displayName` is not necessarily set in the auth user object. So you might want to set a default placeholder that you can query for later and ask the user to provide information for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL",
  authDomain: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL",
  databaseURL: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL",
  projectId: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL",
  storageBucket: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL",
  messagingSenderId: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_CREDENTIAL"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
var firestore = firebase.firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  //check if user is signed in
  if (user) {
    //user is signed in
    //get user display
    if (user.displayName !== undefined) {
      var username = user.displayName;
      //add displayName to firestore
      firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set({
        username: username
      }, {merge: true})
      .then(function() {
        alert('displayName added!');
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        //there was an error writing to firestore
        //check console
        console.log(e);
      });
    } else {
      //user has not set displayName
      alert('no displayName');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your contribution and welcome stakoverflow, but I'm asking about `firestore` not `firebase`